# Is it possible to create Attribute for controller, which executes all query into db via one transaction?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, architecture, data-access-layer

I mean next situation. This example a little bit ugly, but it shows what exactly I want.

```
[MyAttribute]
public MyController
{
     [Post]
     public void CoolStuff(int id, Item item)
     {
          User user = _userRepository.Get(id);

          Bucket bucket = _bucketRepository.Get(user.bucketId);

          bucket.Add(item);

          _bucketRepository.Save(bucket);
     }
}
```

There are 3 queres into db. I want that [MyAttribute] collects these queries in transaction and executes. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). You can derive your custom attribute from ActionFilterAttribute and override two methods:

OnActionExecuting - to open a transaction
OnActionExecuted - to comit or rollback the transaction

Hope it helps!